# Resource leaked in many places Java using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been spending the last 42 mnins trying to figure the error out on why it states

> Resource leaked: 'myFirstname' and many other decleared variables
> including myObj when its ran.

Comment: You should create only one Scanner instance. Normally you should close a scanner, but scanners wrapping `System.in` are an exception, because closing the scanner would also close `System.in`, which means you would no longer be able to get input.

Comment: In any case, you should provide a [mcve] as in: give the full error message etc. You see, for me, I could just compile your code fine, and it runs and does what it is supposed to do (and yes, your problem is that you keep creating new scanner objects all the time).

Comment: A resource leak should only be a warning, not an error. In any case, as Mark wrote, you should be declaring only one scanner and reading all of your input from that one scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one `Scanner`. That **warning** is because you never close the `Scanner`. Normally that is a valuable warning, but when the `Scanner` wraps `System.in` closing it will also close `System.in` so normally you don't close such a `Scanner`. However, you can do so before the program ends; and the easiest way is a `try-with-Resources`. Also, you compare the scanner `myUsername` with the `String` `newUsername` and close an `if` body with an unfortunately placed `;`. Fixing all of that, it should look something like

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Enter your First Name");
    String firstName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");

    String lastName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your Year of Employment");

    String yearVar = scan.nextLine();

    String newUsername = firstName.substring(0, 1) + lastName;
    System.out.println("Username: " + newUsername);

    String newPassword = firstName.substring(0, 3) + yearVar + lastName.substring(0, 3);
    System.out.println("Password: " + newPassword);

    System.out.println("Enter your Username");
    String userName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your Password");
    String passWord = scan.nextLine();

    if (userName.equals(newUsername)) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to change your password?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a lot of Scanner object, and closing none of them. This cause the resources to be leaked. To close them and stop the leaks, add: `myScanner.close()` once you are finished with it.

Besides it could be better to use less scanner objects and reuse one in order to optimize your code.

EDIT: As pointed out by Elliott Frisch answer, closing a scanner wrapping System.in will close it as well, which is usually not wanted.

Comment: Closing a scanner wrapping `System.in` is not a good idea, as that will close `System.in`, which will mean you can no longer accept user input after closing that scanner.